# Converting unknown classTag to Float in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, casting, type-conversion

I have a variable called `data`. This data is of type `Array[ED]`. Now during the runtime, the type of ED can be either `Integer` or `Double`. I wanted to convert this array into an array of `Array[Float]`. I have tried the `data.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[Float].floatValue)`, but unfortunately, it returns an exception of ClassCastException. I wanna know what is the right approach for converting this array?

Comment: How is `ED` defined? (Is it a type synonym, a trait, a class, etc.?)

Comment: Are trying to cast to `Float` from `Double`?

Answer (score 2):

Any `Numeric` value can be turned into a `Float` value.

```
def toFloat[N](n :N)(implicit ev :Numeric[N]) :Float =
  ev.toDouble(n).floatValue()

toFloat(9)     //res0: Float = 9.0
toFloat(9.2D)  //res1: Float = 9.2
```

But if the compiler doesn't recognize your `ED` type as a `Numeric` then this isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collect` to get the values in the `Array`:

```
data.collect{ case n: Number => n.floatValue }
```

This will skip any non-numeric values, so add a `case _` if you want to check for this.

I would also recommend using native Scala types like `List` and `Vector` rather than `Array`, which is just a wrapper around a Java array and doesn't fit so well with the Scala type system.

---

Note that `Number` is a rather awkward because it is a Java type and isn't really in the Scala type hierarchy. If you want to avoid it, this also works:

```
data.map(_.toString.toFloat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this unknown type to `Number` as `Number` is the superclass for all numeric classes.

```
  def convertToFloat[T](arr: Array[T]): Array[Float] = {
    arr.map(_.asInstanceOf[Number].floatValue())
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(convertToFloat(Array(1.234456335664756746, 2.324902485349859)).mkString(", "))
    println(convertToFloat(Array(1, 2, 3)).mkString(", "))
  }
```

Output is:

> 1.2344563, 2.3249025
>
> 1.0, 2.0, 3.0

Comment: `Number` is not actually a superclass of `Int` and `Float`, but there is enough automatic conversion going on to make this work.